# Automatically copy text from element to :before content attribute

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I'm trying to have a scaled text effect on my header, without creating additional text elements. Trying so, I am using the `::before` pseudo element. To create this effect, however, the pseudo-element has to have the same `content` as the actual element. Since this can't be done in HTML and is quite a lot of work in CSS (as it's located multiple times..), I'm looking for a universal method for all the elements with this effect.

[image]

I was thinking of going the jQuery way with a `.attr()` function to copy the text and append it to the pseudo-element, but as far as I know this can't be done.

```
$(function() {
  $('h1').each(function() {
    var Text = "$(`this`).text()";
    $('this::before').attr('content', Text);
  });
});
```

Is there an alternative?

---

<sub>CSS for the effect, currently, is relatively simple.</sub>

```
:before {
  transform: scale(1.5)
  opacity: .2
  content: "text here"
}
```

Comment: I tried to explain that in the first paragraph. This effect is applied to each `H1` element, placed once on each page in the `header`. Well, current perspective is there'll be only 5 pages and that isn't that much extra CSS lines.. I was simply hoping for a simple single method in case there'll be many more pages, which means more CSS lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cant access psuedo element with javascript but, you can acces element with CSS. 
Check the snippet.

```css
h1::before{
  content: attr(data-before);
}
```

```html
<h1 data-before="Before Content">
Some Content
</h1>
```

I guess you don't even need javascript. Edited The Snippet.

Comment: Wow, this is pretty clever!

Comment: Quick update: content needs it content within quotes, i.e. "attr(data-before)". At least, it does in Chrome to actual have content show up.

Comment: Hm, I think I wrote/copied the javascript wrong, since once I added it to the html instead, it worked. 

You are amazing dude.